# parse fields of xml output in order to get text of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple function to parse some fields of the following xml output. My intention is to parse only the acl field and assigned groups. But i'm not sure if the function i wrote is the most effective way to do it.

Output from requests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Values version="2.0">
  <array name="aclgroups" type="record" depth="1">
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
      <value name="name">ACL_DEV_TEAM</value>
      <Boolean name="inUse">true</Boolean>
      <array name="allow" type="value" depth="1">
        <value>groups_a</value>
        <value>groups_b</value>
      </array>
      </array>
      <array name="userList" type="value" depth="1">
        <value>jonhn</value>
        <value>bob</value>
      </array>
    </record>
  </array>
</Values>
```

Code to parse the xml result

```
def parse_xml_list(self):
    try:
        acl_list = []
        tree = ElementTree.fromstring(self.xml)
        #Loop over all entries ( in this exemple is reduced to one only )
        for records in tree.findall('./array/record'):
            #Again.. loop over all records on xml
            acl = records.find('value[@name="name"]').text
            print(acl)
            for groups in records.findall('./array[1]/value'):
                print(groups.text)

            print()
    except Exception:
        raise
    finally:
        self.xml = None
```

Expected Result:

```
devteam
group_a
group_b
```

The code is working great, but how could i turn it more Pythonic ?

thanks in advance.